# Help me pick a Dependency Injection framework for .Net

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which C#/.NET Dependency Injection frameworks are worth looking into?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288/which-c-net-dependency-injection-frameworks-are-worth-looking-into)

Yes I know this question has been asked many times, but the various frameworks keep evolving, so I would like a fresh answer on the subject.

A few thoughts about the framework, they are not necessary black or white, but rather my preferences.

Things I like:

- Convention based registrations
- Constructor injection
- Can also target Silverlight
- Small footprint
- One assembly
- Fast

Thing I don't like:

- Xml
- Custom attributes
- [Service locator pattern](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#UsingAServiceLocator)

Things I don't think about:

- Linq
- Opensource

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267567/what-should-i-consider-when-choosing-a-dependency-injection-framework-for-net http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288/which-c-net-dependency-injection-frameworks-are-worth-looking-into

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you might want to try [NInject](http://ninject.org/).

It has a definite focus on being easy to use with little configuration overhead (no bulky XML config files, etc). It even comes with a nice, shiny, fluent interface to make things understandable.

Comment: I've used Ninject on several projects and I really like it. It fulfills all of your requirements (except I don't know about Silverlight).

Answer (score 1):

[autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/)

[Ninject](http://ninject.org/)

Answer (score 0):

When you're not familiar yet with any of the big DI frameworks, you might consider the very easy [SimpleServiceLocator](http://simpleservicelocator.codeplex.com) (shameless plug). Let's compare it to your check list:

- Constructor injection, check!
- Can also target Silverlight, check!
- Small footprint, check!
- One assembly, nope 2. It needs the [Common Service Locator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com).
- Fast, double check!
- No Xml, check! Only code based configuration is supported.
- No Custom attributes, check! It is completely attribute free.
- No Service locator pattern, check. Despite its name, you can do DI with it (just look at the examples on the site).
- Open source, check! MIT License.

The idea behind the Simple Service Locator is:

> to provide .NET application developers
>   with a inversion of control (IoC)
>   framework that is truly easy to use,
>   while allowing developers to replace
>   it with a more feature-rich IoC
>   framework when needed.
>
> The Simple Service Locator is an
>   implementation of the Common Service
>   Locator library. The Common Service
>   Locator is a shared interface for
>   inversion of control and dependency
>   injection which application and
>   framework developers can reference.